# Python sql query taking up 3x memory than table size?

Tags: python

I am running a very simple query using python on a table from Snowflake database using the package `snowflake-connector-python==2.3.3` installed with the additional `[pandas]` I containerized my python app using the `python:3.7.0-slim` image. And my script is extremely simple.

```
from snowflake import connector

import os

ctx = connector.connect(
    user=os.environ['USER'],
    password=os.environ['PASSWORD'],
    account=os.environ['ACCOUNT'],
    warehouse=os.environ['WAREHOUSE'],
    database=os.environ['DATABASE'],
    schema=os.environ['SCHEMA'])

cur = ctx.cursor()

# Execute a statement that will generate a result set.
sql = "SELECT * FROM MY_TABLE ORDER BY MY_COLUMN"

print("executing query: " + sql)

cur.execute(sql)

df = cur.fetch_pandas_all()
```

The actual table size from what Snowflake tells me is 3.3 GB. However when I run this app it crashes as it takes over 9GB of RAM. I know this because I'm running it in a kubernetes cluster and the pod is evicted and says it used `9535336Ki` memory. Is there something I'm missing here? How can the memory usage be 3x the table size?

Comment: This may not be simple: `SELECT * FROM`. See [why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful). Try selecting exact needed columns for app.

Comment: One of the top comment's reads `It's acceptable to use SELECT * when there's the explicit need for every column in the table(s) involved`. And I need every column. Also it still doesn't answer the question: the table itself is 3.3 GB but the size of my container grows beyond 9GB so why is that?

Comment: Understood but for maintainable code, always a good idea to specify explicitly the columns and in consistent order in case underlying table or code changes. For debugging, try selecting one, two, three, etc.. columns at a time one and check RAM usage. Watch for large data types (object, arrays, geospatial). I also wonder about `cur.fetch_pandas_all()`. Try removing for debugging reasons to isolate problematic line. [Docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#label-python-connector-api-fetch-pandas-all) indicate faster than pandas' `read_sql` but I wonder.

Comment: Cool thank you for the callout - I should be a bit more specific. When I put the pipeline in production I will switch to naming all columns. I actually found a similar issue in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41253326/pandas-using-too-much-memory-with-read-sql-table . I'm thinking it might be a pandas related thing